# biblatex: different output for one, two, or three authors

Tags: spacing, biblatex, punctuation

I'm using/customizing the `verbose` style in `biblatex`. This is the desired output, depending on the number of authors (just focussing on the authors):

> Apple, Anthony. *Title*. **[⇦ 1 author]**
>   Banana, Barbara/Chris Coconut. *Title*. **[⇦ 2 authors]**
>   Date, Donna et al. *Title*. **[⇦ >2 authors]**

I've almost got it figured out, there's just one space that I can't get rid of:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose,%
            maxnames=2,minnames=1,%
            maxitems=2,minitems=1]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{one,
    author = {Anthony Apple},
    title = {Title}}
@book{two,
    author = {Barbara Banana and Chris Coconut},
    title = {Title}}
@book{three,
    author = {Donna Date and Eric Eggplant and Fred Fig},
    title = {Title}}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  and = {\unspace/}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}% adds all entries to the bibliography

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output with spurious space]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you actually want to use the slash as a delimiter in all languages, you can just redefine `\finalnamedelim` - a delimiter printed before the final name in a name list. In `biblatex.def` it is defined as follows.

```
\newcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

This will make use of slash in both citations and the bibliography:

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}
```

And this will use slash only in the bibliography:

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifbibliography
    {\addslash}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Languages don't really matter, in the end, everything's gonna be in `ngerman`. But I'd like to have the slash in the bibliography as well as in the citations. For that, I don't need to keep any of the original definition of `\finalnamedelim` and just replace it by `{\addslash}`?

Comment: @doncherry That's right. I edited the answer.